# Custom ASP.Net Server Controls: How to call javascript function in parent page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have built a number of custom server controls and routinely call javascript functions that are embedded into my controls. But I haven't been able to figure out how to create a property that the user of the control can add their own function to and their javascript function in the page containing the control will be called. I need to do something like `OnClientClick` for an `asp:Button` control.

*Edit 1:*

Thanks to the answer by @h2015 I have made progress on this.

In my control I create a public property for the user's script,

```
public string EditAddressScript
{
  set
  {
    string scriptName = "EditAddressScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();
    ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;

    string scriptText = string.Format("function EditAddress() {{{0}}}", value);

    csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, scriptName, scriptText, true);
  }
}
```

Then in the `RenderContents` section of my control I check whether a value has been specified for `EditAddressScript` and create a button if it has.

```
output.Write("<input id='btnEdit' type='button' value='Edit Address' style='font-size: 6pt;' onclick='EditAddress();' />");
```

The page that uses this control creates it dynamically so I do something like this,

```
ECFControls.DefendantAddressReview defendantAddress = new ECFControls.DefendantAddressReview();
divControls.Controls.Add(defendantAddress);
defendantAddress.ClientEditAddressScript = "alert('Hello, World');";
```

This works, but is far from optimal.

- I would like to define the script in the aspx page and then just give my control the name of the script, rather than setting the value of `EditAddressScript` to the actual javascript code.
- In the `RenderContents` section of the control I have the name of the script hardcoded I would like that to be dynamic.

*Edit 2:*

Okay, it looks like I was making this far more complicated than necessary. All that is needed is to create a script in the parent aspx page and set the event in the control to that script.

So this is what I have now

Add script to aspx page.

```
    function EditAddress() {
      alert("Hello, World");
    }
```

Create a property in the control to hold the value (`_EditAddressScript` is a private string variable in the control)

```
public string EditAddressScript
{
  set
  {
    _EditAddressScript = value;
  }
}
```

Then in the `RenderContents` section of the control I check whether a value has been specified for `EditAddressScript` and create a button if it has.

```
        if(_EditAddressScript.Trim() != "")
          output.Write(string.Format("<input id='btnEdit' type='button' value='Edit' style='font-size: 6pt;' onclick='{0}' />", _EditAddressScript));
```

Create the control like this,

```
    ECFControls.DefendantAddressReview defendantAddress = new ECFControls.DefendantAddressReview();
    divControls.Controls.Add(defendantAddress);
    defendantAddress.EditAddressScript = "EditAddress()";
```

If the control were created declaratively I could do this,

```
      <ECF:DefendantAddressReview ID="defendantAddressReview" runat="server" EditAddressScript="EditAddress()" />
```

Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored two possible solutions in the edits to my original question. The second edit achieves the desired result. I wanted to have an optional property for a custom ASP.Net server control that would specify the name of a javascript function that the user of the control could place in the same page as the control. Here's how I did it.

Add a public string property to the server control that defines the name of your javascript function.  (`_CustomJavascript` is a private string variable in the control)

```
public string CustomJavascript
{
  set
  {
    _CustomJavascript = value;
  }
}
```

Then in the `RenderContents` section of the control check whether a value has been specified for `_CustomJavascript` and add the code to call that javascript if it has been. In my case I was creating a composite control and wanted an edit button to display that would call the user's javascript function.

```
if(_CustomJavascript.Trim() != "")
      output.Write(string.Format("<input id='btnEdit' type='button' value='Edit' style='font-size: 6pt;' onclick='{0}' />", _CustomJavascript));
```

All the user has to do is write their function.

```
function EditAddress() {
  alert("Hello, World");
}
```

And give the name of their function to the `CustomJavascript` property when declaring the control.

```
  <cc:AddressReview ID="addressReview" runat="server" CustomJavascript="EditAddress()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this.Page.ClientScript.Register...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @h2015. I have used that family of methods before, but it didn't seem like they were the solution to this. I've looked into them further and added a somewhat workable solution to my original question.